# How type BehaviorSubject of rxjs with type predicate?

Tags: rxjs, typescript-typings

Here is my code. I am getting the error below.

```js
type Filters = {
  type: 'expenses' | 'income'
  week: string
  month: string
  category: string
}
```

```js
class SubjectManager {
  private subject$: BehaviorSubject<Filters> = new BehaviorSubject({
    category: 'all',
    week: '1',
    month: '10',
    type: 'expenses'
  })
}
```

> Error
>
> Type 'Filters' cannot be assigned to type '{ category: string; week: string; month: string; type: "expenses";

How can I fix this error?

Comment: the value "all" is assigned to the category property whose type is "string"

Comment: @BizzyBob Order of properties is not the same, so types are actually correct.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```js
class SubjectManager {
  private subject$ = new BehaviorSubject<Filters>({
    category: 'all',
    week: '1',
    month: '10',
    type: 'expenses'
  })
}
```

The original code doesn't work because the object inside `BehaviorSubject` has type `{ type: 'expenses', ... }`, not `{ type: 'expenses' | 'income', ... }`.